# How to copy documents from one folder to another in SharePoint document library using client object model?

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, csom, sharepoint-library, document-migration

I want to copy documents from one folder to another within same document library along with metadata (retaining metadata from source) using client object model with Microsoft. SharePoint.Client.dll